# How to edit the data in this column in sqlite database

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a `CustomerOrders` table in my database and it has an `orders` column which stores the orders of the user, first of all this is my table and the datatype I used for `orders` column (I followed a tutorial)

```
class JsonEncodedDict(db.TypeDecorator):
    impl = db.Text

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        if value is None:
            return '{}'
        else:
            return json.dumps(value)

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        if value is None:
            return {}
        else:
            return json.loads(value)


class CustomerOrder(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    invoice = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    status = db.Column(db.String(20), default='Pending', nullable=False)

    customer_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(
        'customers.id'), nullable=False)
    customer = db.relationship('Customers', back_populates='orders')

    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow, nullable=False)
    orders = db.Column(JsonEncodedDict)
```

and an example of how the data in order is stored is like this:

```
{"1": {"file": null, "image": "fd42dbf4212ddfd8c76b.png", "name": "p1", "price": "6.00", "quantity": "3"}, 
"2": {"file": null, "image": "52556d918e2e490032c0.jpg", "name": "p2", "price": "3.00", "quantity": "3"}}
```

and in my case, after the customer pays for an order he can upload a file for each product and I want to update the `file` in `orders` to the name of the file uploaded after saving it
but I'm facing a problem where data in the database doesn't update and it stays the same, I tried to do it using this method:

```
@app.route('/upload_file/<int:code>', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@login_required
def upload_file(code):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files.get('order_file')
        invoice = request.args.get('invoice')
        order = CustomerOrder.query.filter_by(invoice=invoice).first()
        try:
            file_name = secrets.token_hex(10) + '.pdf'
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], file_name))
            data = {}
            for key, item in order.orders.items():
                existing_data = item
                if int(key) == code:
                    existing_data['file'] = file_name
                    data[str(key)] = existing_data
                    order.orders = data
                    db.session.commit()
                    flash(
                        f'{item["name"]}\'s file has been uploaded.', 'success')
                    return redirect(url_for('orders'))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return redirect(url_for('orders'))
```

in this code, the `orders` in the database is updated but only to the product with the uploaded file, so if the order had 3 items after uploading a file for one of them the order now has only 1 item, so I fixed the code like this:

```
try:
            file_name = secrets.token_hex(10) + '.pdf'
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], file_name))
            data = {}
            for key, item in order.orders.items():
                existing_data = item
                if int(key) == code:
                    existing_data['file'] = file_name
                data[str(key)] = existing_data
                order.orders = data
            db.session.commit()
            flash(
                        f'{item["name"]}\'s file has been uploaded.', 'success')
            return redirect(url_for('orders'))
```

but now the database doesn't change at all and it stays the same, I've been trying to solve it for 2 days and nothing is working, thought about changing the whole way I store the `orders` in  my database but if I do it i need to change a lot of things too, so I'm giving it a last try here before doing it.

Comment: you probably need `from sqlalchemy.orm.attributes import flag_modified` and before you commit do `flag_modified(order, 'orders')`

Answer (score 0):

please store while orders as table without it you will be in trouble anyway in the feature.

If not! My advice you can save it without for loop kinda like this:

```
    file_name = secrets.token_hex(10) + '.pdf'
    file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], file_name))
    order = CustomerOrder.query.filter_by(invoice=invoice).first()
    order.orders[str(key)]['file'] = file_name
    db.session.commit()
```